# Whonix + Android VM

Tags: whonix

I'm running a whonix gateway as well as an Android VM via Genymotion.

Would it be possible to route my traffic on the Android VM through the whonix gateway?

I know whonix can be used in conjunction with other OSes but have been unable to find anything regarding whonix and Android.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111790/whonix-android-vm

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/). It doesn't look like it's internally using VirtualBox or any other virtualizer such as KVM, qemu, etc.

Therefore I wouldn't know how to put the Android VM behind a Whonix-Gateway VM.

I see only two alternatives.

- Try installing the Android VM inside a Whonix[(-Custom)](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Other_Operating_Systems)-Workstation.
- Or use [Whonix with Physical Isolation](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Physical%20Isolation).